# Use value of buffer-local variable in another buffer

Tags: emacs, scope, elisp

How can you process a buffer local variable in another buffer?  I thought I could just bind it with let, but am having trouble passing the variable to another function that uses `symbol-value`.  Here is a small example,

```
(defvar-local local-var nil)
(setq local-var "a")

(defun fun ()
  (let ((local-var local-var))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (format-fun 'local-var)
      (message (buffer-string)))))

(defun format-fun (name)
  (insert (symbol-value name)))
```

How can I bind `local-var` in `fun` so `format-fun` can process it in another buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the variable with `let` doesn't stop it from being reassigned when switching buffers.

Use a different variable to avoid this.

```
(defun fun ()
  (let ((new-var local-var))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (format-fun 'new-var)
      (message (buffer-string)))))
```

Comment: I tried my function and it worked fine. I'm using Emacs 22, so it doesn't have `defvar-local`, but I did it with `make-local-variable`.

Comment: I don't see how your solution could help. Binding the same variable twice just shadows the first binding.

Comment: I needed to change `format-fun`, because `(insert (symbol-value name))` gets an error if the value is `nil`. I changed it to `(insert (format "%s" (symbol-value name)))`

Comment: Then you have to make sure that the value of the variable is always a string

Comment: And it shouldn't contain any `%` characters, either. The syntax of `message` is `(message format-string args...)`

Comment: I tried again with `make-variable-buffer-local`, and my function still worked. What do you see when you try it?

Answer (score 4):

There is an *elisp* function to get a *buffer-local* variable value from another buffer:

```
(buffer-local-value 'var (get-buffer  "your-buffer-name"))
```